# BinarySearchTree remove method malfunctioning when removing integers

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I wrote the BinaryTree structure from scratch, which included a remove(Object obj) method to remove elements from said tree. It seems to function correctly for every type except an Integer, and I can't figure out why.

```
public BinaryTree<E> remove(Object obj) {
        try{
            E value = (E)obj;
            int cmp = value.compareTo(this.value); 
            if(cmp == 0) {
                List<BinaryTree<E>> kids = children();
                if(kids.size() == 0) {
                    return new EmptyBinarySearchTree<E>();
                }
                if(kids.size() == 1) {
                    return kids.get(0);
                }
                //2 children
                BinaryTree<E> successor = ((BinarySearchTree)right).smallest();
                BinaryTree<E> result = remove(successor.getValue());
                result.setValue(successor.getValue());
                return result;
            }
            if(cmp < 0) {
                left = left.remove(value);
            }
            if(cmp > 0) {
                right = right.remove(value);
            }
        }
        catch(ClassCastException cce) {

        }
        return this;
    }
```

I'm driving the BinaryTree with the following, which also implements Set that I built:

```
package setDriver;
import set.*;
import list.*;

public class HwTreeSetDriver
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Set <Integer> values;
        values = new TreeSet <Integer> ();


    values.add (3);
    values.add (5);
    values.add (3);



    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
         values.add (j * 10);


    Iterator<Integer> itty = values.iterator();
    while (itty.hasNext())
        if (itty.next() % 2 == 1)
            itty.remove();              // remove odd numbers


}
```

}

After running the driver, the size is still 6, and the set contains 3, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40.

The following is the remove(Object obj) method in TreeSet, which in turn calls the remove method I posted initially:

```
public boolean remove(Object obj){
    if(!contains(obj)) return false;

    tree = tree.remove(obj);
    size--;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, what does it do? Without working code or error messages/stack traces, there isn't much to go on.

Comment: Is `remove` overloaded? Is there a `remove(int)` version?

Comment: Show us the code you're using to drive this when you test it.

Comment: I don't see the connection between the 2 pieces of code.

Comment: This type of question should be clarified deeper by debugging. Can you identify where "every other object" and integers differ in execution?

Comment: It's not even clear that your `remove(object)` method is being invoked at all. Also, calling your own class `TreeSet` is only going to confuse everybody!

Answer (score -1):

[Is int an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700573/is-int-an-object-in-java)

int is not considered a object 
here a question on stackoverflow for proof

Comment: Is this relevant? OP says "It seems to function correctly for every type except an **Integer**", which is a reference type, and not the same thing as `int`.

Comment: but the function takes an object,,,,,

Comment: Oh go look up autoboxing