# Issue with Iterator remove method in TreeSet class

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, iterator, set

So for my Data Structures and Algorithms class we've been rebuilding the java.util package.  I know a similar question has been posted here at: [BinarySearchTree remove method malfunctioning when removing integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452088/binarysearchtree-remove-method-malfunctioning-when-removing-integers) but that unfortunately was not specific enough to describe the issue.  Here is the driver & output:

```
import set.*;
import list.*;

public class HwTreeSetDriver
{
public static void main()
{
    Set <Integer> values;
    values = new TreeSet <Integer> ();

    if (!values.isEmpty())
        System.err.println  ("Error in isEmpty ");

    values.add (3);
    values.add (5);
    values.add (3);

    // No news is good news

    if (values.size() != 2)
        System.err.println  ("Error in size ");
     if (values.isEmpty())
        System.err.println  ("Error in isEmpty ");

    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
         values.add (j * 10);

    if (values.contains (15))
        System.err.println ("Error in contains ");
    if (!values.contains (20))
        System.err.println ("Error in contains ");  

    if (values.remove (2))
        System.err.println ("Error in remove ");  
    if (!values.remove (0))
        System.err.println ("Error in remove ");  
    if (values.size() != 6)
        System.err.println  ("Error in size or remove ");

    Iterator<Integer> itty = values.iterator();
    while (itty.hasNext())
        if (itty.next() % 2 == 1)
            itty.remove();              // remove odd numbers

    System.out.println ("After removing odd values, set is " + values);
    System.out.println ("size is " + values.size());
    if (values.size() != 4)
        System.err.println  ("Error in size or iterator ");

    values.clear();
    if (!values.isEmpty())
        System.err.println  ("Error in clear or isEmpty ");

    values.add (17);

    System.out.println ("Testing complete");

}
}
```

The driver provides the following output:

```
After removing odd values, set is [3, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40]
size is 6
Testing complete

Error in size or iterator
```

The issue is that when the values tree is inspected, the values are all still there, but when you look at the values tree inside of the TreeIterator(seen lower) the tree inside of it is correct.  It seems to never update the original tree (values).  I've been trying to find why it does not, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue.  The driver function with java.util.* to prove that it will give a correct output.

Here is the TreeSet class:

```
package set;
import tree.*;
import list.*;

public class TreeSet<E extends Comparable <E>> implements Set<E>{
BinaryTree<E> tree = new EmptyBinarySearchTree<E>();
int size = 0;

public int size(){
    return size;
}

public boolean add(E value){
    if(tree.containsKey(value))
        return false;
    tree = tree.add(value);
    size++;
    return true;
}

public boolean contains(Object obj){
    E value;
    try{
        value = (E) obj;
        return tree.containsKey(value);
    }
    catch(ClassCastException cce){
        return false;
    }
}

public void clear(){
    tree = new EmptyBinarySearchTree();
    size = 0;
}

public boolean remove(Object obj){
    if(!(contains(obj)))
        return false;
    tree = tree.remove(obj);
    size--;
    return true;
}

public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    return tree.iterator();
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return size == 0;
}

public String toString(){
    return tree.toString();
}
}
```

And here is the BinarySearchTree that it is using:

```
package tree;
import list.*;

public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements BinaryTree<E>{

BinaryTree<E> left;
BinaryTree<E> right;
E value;
public BinarySearchTree(E value){
    this.value=value;
    left=new EmptyBinarySearchTree<E>();
    right=new EmptyBinarySearchTree<E>();
}

public BinaryTree<E> getLeft(){
    return left;
}

public BinaryTree<E> getRight(){
    return right;
}

public BinaryTree<E> add(E value){
    int cmp = value.compareTo(this.value);
    if(cmp<0)
        left = left.add(value);
    if(cmp>0)
        right = right.add(value);
    return this;
}

public boolean containsKey(E value){
    int cmp = value.compareTo(this.value);        
    if(cmp==0)
        return true;
    if(cmp<0)
        return left.containsKey(value);
    return right.containsKey(value);
}

public E getValue(){
    return this.value;
}

public E get(E value){
    int cmp = value.compareTo(this.value);
    if(cmp<0)
        return left.get(value);
    if(cmp>0)
        return right.get(value);
    return this.value;
}

private BinaryTree<E> smallest(){
    if(left instanceof BinarySearchTree){
        return ((BinarySearchTree<E>)left).smallest();
    }
    return this;
}

public BinaryTree<E> remove(Object obj){
    try{E value = (E) obj;
        int cmp = value.compareTo(this.value);
        if(cmp==0){
            List<BinaryTree<E>>kids = children();
            if(kids.size()==0)
                return new EmptyBinarySearchTree<E>();
            if(kids.size()==1)
                return kids.get(0);
            //2 Children
            BinaryTree<E> successor = ((BinarySearchTree)right).smallest();
            BinaryTree<E> result = remove(successor.getValue());
            result.setValue(successor.getValue());
            return result;
        }
        if(cmp<0)
            left = left.remove(value);
        if(cmp>0)
            right = right.remove(value);
    }
    catch(ClassCastException ece){}
    return this;
}

private List<BinaryTree<E>> children(){
    List<BinaryTree<E>>result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(left instanceof BinarySearchTree){
        result.add(left);
    }
    if(right instanceof BinarySearchTree){
        result.add(right);
    }
    return result;
}

public void setValue(E value){
    this.value=value;
}

public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    return new TreeIterator<E>(this);
}

public String toString(){
    String result = "[";
    Iterator<E> itty = iterator();
    while(itty.hasNext()){
        result+=itty.next();
        if(itty.hasNext()){
            result+=", ";
        }
    }
    result+="]";
    return result;
}

public void setRight(BinaryTree<E>right){
    right=right;
}

public void setLeft(BinaryTree<E>left){
    left=left;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return value == null;
}

public E getLargest(){
    if(right instanceof BinarySearchTree){
        return ((BinarySearchTree<E>)right).getLargest();
    }
    return this.value;
}
}
```

And finally here is the TreeIterator it uses:

```
package tree;
import list.*;
import queue.*;

public class TreeIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>{
private BinaryTree<E>tree;
private QueueADT<E>queue = new ArrayQueue<>();
private E lastGotten;
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class TreeIterator
 */
public TreeIterator(BinaryTree<E> tree){
    this.tree=tree;
    this.buildQ(tree);
}

private void buildQ(BinaryTree<E> tree){
    if(tree.getLeft() instanceof BinarySearchTree)
        buildQ(tree.getLeft());
    queue.add(tree.getValue());
    if(tree.getRight() instanceof BinarySearchTree)
        buildQ(tree.getRight());
}

public boolean hasNext(){
    return !queue.isEmpty();
}

public E next(){
    lastGotten=queue.remove();
    return lastGotten;
}

public void remove(){
    tree=tree.remove(lastGotten);
}

}
```

These are all here for reference as nothing of java.util is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by creating iterator specifically tailored to TreeSet.  Similar implementation for a HashSet iterator for future reference.

```
package set;
import tree.*;
import list.*;

public class TreeSetIterator<E extends Comparable <E>> extends          TreeIterator<E>{
TreeSet<E> set;

public TreeSetIterator(TreeSet<E> set){
    super(set.tree);
    this.set=set;
}

public void remove(){
    set.tree=set.tree.remove(getLastGotten());
    set.size--;
}
}
```